# Memory leak,copy constructor,assign operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, copy-constructor

**Everthing is in the code**

*Here is code. Constructor's.*

```
 Polynomial::Polynomial()
 {
 base=0;
 Coefficients=new int [base+1];
 Coefficients[0]=0;
 }
```

*Basically creates Poly equals to 0;*

```
 Polynomial::Polynomial(const unsigned int length,const int* table)
 {
 base=length;
 bool a=false;

 for(int i=length;i>=0;i--)
 {
 if(table[i]==1&&a==false)
 {
 a=true;

 Coefficients=new int[base+1];
 };

 if(table[i]==0&&a==false)
 {
 base--;
 };
 if(a==true)
 Coefficients[i]=table[i];
 }
 }
```

*Here we create Poly with given length(it can be higher than Poly base)*
*I think so far everything is ok.*
*Now copy constructor:*

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& P)
{

base = P.base;
Coefficients=new int[base+1];
for(unsigned int i=0; i<base+1;i++)
{
Coefficients[i]=P.Coefficients[i];
}
}
```

*And assign operator:*

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator =(const Polynomial &P)
{

base=P.base;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<P.base+1;i++)
Coefficients[i]= P.Coefficients[i];

return *this;
}
```

*I think there is smth wrong with this because when i overloaded + operator*
*And created Polynomial a,u,v;*
*When i typed a=v+u;*
*Sometimes i had garbage values and " Process returned -1073741819        (0xC0000005)"*
*I've read some about switch/copy but is there simple solution in my code     that I am missing on?*

```
Polynomial operator +(const Polynomial& a,const Polynomial& b)
{
Polynomial c;
if(a.base>=b.base)
    c.base=a.base;

    else
        c.base=b.base;

c.Coefficients=new int[c.base+1];
for(unsigned int i=0;i<c.base+1;i++)
{
c.Coefficients[i]=0;
};
for(unsigned int i=0;i<b.base+1;i++)
{
c.Coefficients[i]=b.Coefficients[i];

};
for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.base+1;i++)
{
c.Coefficients[i]+=a.Coefficients[i];

}
return c;
}
```

*Here is destructor*

```
Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
delete []Coefficients;

}
```

*+= operator*

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator +=(const Polynomial& a)
{
if(a.base>base)
   {

base=a.base;
Coefficients = (int*)realloc(Coefficients, (base+1)*sizeof(int));



for(unsigned int i=0;i<base+1;i++)
{
    if(Coefficients[i]!=0&&Coefficients[i]!=1)
    {
        Coefficients[i]=0;
    }

 Coefficients[i]+=a.Coefficients[i];


 }
   }
   if(a.base<=base)
     {

for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.base+1;i++)
{
Coefficients[i]+=a.Coefficients[i];

}
}
return *this;
}
```

Comment: please add the overloaded + operator so we can help. Also, when you implement the copy/assign constructor you should take care of the memory allocated for Coefficients. If you're coping / assigning a  Polynomial which is not "this", you should delete Coefficients

Comment: Do you have a destructor defined for `Polynomial`?  If so 1) please post it and 2) the assignment operator is very simple to implement without any memory leaks using the copy constructor and destructor as helpers.

Comment: There is no need for manual memory management.

Comment: Yes, there is no need for manual memory management, but just for the exercise, the answer is very simple once the requested functions (destructor and `operator +`) are posted.

Comment: Why are you using `realloc` in a C++ program?  You are mixing up two different memory allocation schemes -- you can't `delete[]` something created with `realloc`.  Make your life easier and just use `std::vector<int>`, since you're making a lot of mistakes.

Comment: I thought to use realloc here is nice way of solving this problem i didn't

Comment: i thought i just need to resize the table

Comment: Since you're thinking on such high-level, why didn't you simply use `std::vector<int>` to begin with, instead of low-level pointers and memory management?  `std::vector` has a `resize()` function.  You also would not need a user-defined copy constructor or assignment operator (or destructor) if you had used `std::vector<int>`

Comment: I learn c++ and how to handle memory in c++,i can't use vector i have to use low-level pointers and memory managment.

Comment: You can't mix up memory management functions.  You cannot use `realloc` and `delete[]` on the same pointer.  If you're going to use pointers and memory management, this should have been known well before-hand.

Comment: Ok, i changed it but garbage values and " Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" bug still appears.

Comment: Of course the bug still appears, since you have a lot of errors.  You are not properly deleting the previous memory allocated, thus the memory leaks.

Comment: @Pawneder Change coefficients to a std::vector, like in my updated answer. It's less error prone and you don't have to worry about memory.

Comment: So when i use copy constructor and assign operator i should just use delete[] Coefficients before i start to allocate new memory? I read some article and it was not recomended so what should i do?

Comment: @Pawneder Also, if your goal is to write a Polynomial class, you're being stopped in your goal by memory management issues.  So your goal is not to write a Polynomial class, but to really write a home-made `std::vector` class, because that is what this all boils down to.

Comment: Like i said I am not here to make it easy with std:vector i just want to learn about c++ memory and memory allocation.

Comment: @Pawneder *Like i said I am not here to make it easy with std:vector* -- Then forego this and write a real vector class.  That way you will 1) Really learn memory management properly by writing such a class and 2) You can use your home-made class in your Polynomial class.

Comment: We never got to see how you're using Polynomial instances outside this scope. E.g. in your main() function. @Pawneder

Comment: @Pawneder Might as well [learn by example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6cdc0fe13c58f15).  Otherwise the real answer to your question is a rewrite of your code, not a mere simple fix here or there.

Comment: @Pawneder `operator +` can be written `{ return Polynomial(a) += b; }`.  But this only works once you work out the bugs, use `std::vector`, or use a working example of a viector class I posted in the previous comments.